# How are these cdf partitioned?

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image]

In the solution, it says for $x \leq 0$, it's $P(X \leq x)$, but shouldn't it be $P(X \leq 0)$ or $P(x \leq X \leq 0)$? Also, on that same line, how did it go from $e^{-|y|}$ to $e^{y}$?

And for the second line, why is $F_X(0)$ there, but it wasn't there for  $x \leq 0$?

Comment: By definition $F_X(x) = \Pr(X \leq x)$, irrespective of the value of $x$. For the case when $x \leq 0$, the integration variable $y$ goes from $-\infty$ to $x$, and thus is always negative. Consequently, $e^{-|y|} = e^y$. For $x \geq 0$, $F_X(x) = \Pr(X \leq x) = \Pr(X \leq 0) + \Pr(0 < X \leq x) = F_X(0) + \Pr(0 < X \leq x)$. To compute $F_X(x)$ for $x \leq 0$, it is not required to split it into two cases as the PDF is same throughout $(-\infty, x)$.

Comment: But I don't understand why it is P(X ≤ 0) + P(0 < X ≤ x). Why was it split into two cases?

Comment: When you try to evaluate $F_X(x)$ using the integral of PDF, notice that the function will change at $x = 0$ from $e^x$ to $e^{-x}$. Therefore, you need to split the integral to evaluate it which is exactly why that expression has been split too.

Answer (score 1):

**In the solution, it says for $x \leq 0$, it's $P(X \leq x)$, but shouldn't it be $P(X \leq 0)$ or $P(x \leq X \leq 0)$?**

As sudeep mentioned you are missing the definition of CDF.

*The cumulative distribution function is the probability that the variable takes a value less than or equal to x. That is*

$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)$

**Also, on that same line, how did it go from $e^{-|y|}$ to $e^{y}$?**

Definition of absolute function says

$|y|= \begin{cases} 
      -y & -\infty < y < 0 \\
      \ \  y& \ \  0 \leq y < \infty \\
   \end{cases}$

substituting $-y$ gives $e^{y}$

**And for the second line, why is $F_X(0)$ there, but it wasn't there for  $x \leq 0$?**

Again using the definition of CDF which gives probability less than or equals $x$. When you are computing CDF for $x>0$ you have to add the probability for $x<0$. When we were calculating $P(X<x)$ for $-\infty<x<0$ there was nothing to add because  $F(-\infty)=0$.

Does it help?